# Return associated DataGridView row to it's corresponding Datatable row

Tags: vb.net

Reformatting this question since nobody seemed to understand it. I have a datatable called dtCSV. I am searching through dtCSV for a specific value and I am able to find the row I need ( i dont need help with this part) . dtCSV is also bound to a datagridview. (this is what I need help with) How can I take my row that I found with the search and find it's corresponding row in the datagridview control so that I can highlight that entire row? Thanks

```
Function GetDebitorsString(ByVal Name As String, ByVal RowName As String) As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    If System.IO.File.Exists("data\debitors\debitors.xml") Then
        dt.ReadXml("data\debitors\debitors.xml")
    Else
        MsgBox("File data\debitors\debitors.xml was not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Warning")
        Return String.Empty
    End If


    Dim FoundRow() As DataRow = dt.Select("Name='" & Name & "'")
    If FoundRow IsNot Nothing Then
        Return FoundRow(0).Item(RowName).ToString
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function

Private Sub btnScan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScan.Click
    'looks through all the bills in the CSV and see's if they match with the inputted bills. If they match the cleared date is inputted into the cleared column and the row is turned green in the csv dgv

    For Each row In dt.Rows 'loop through each of the bills listed looking for a matching bank statement with the same amount paid
        If GetDebitorsString(row("Name").ToString, "Search") IsNot String.Empty Then 'find the search string for the debitor
            Dim FoundRow() As DataRow = dtCSV.Select("Description Like '*" & GetDebitorsString(row("Name").ToString, "Search") & "*'") 'try to see if any bank statements match the search string
            If FoundRow.Count >= 0 Then
                'item was found 
                If row("Amount Paid").ToString IsNot String.Empty Then 'ignore bills with no amounts typed in 
                    If Convert.ToDouble(row("Amount Paid")) = Convert.ToDouble(FoundRow(0).Item("Debit")) Then 'if the amount listed in the bill matches the amount in the bank statement 
                        row("Cleared") = FoundRow(0).Item("Date").ToString 'set the date it cleared in the cleared cell

                    End If

                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: No need to loop. Certainly not on the DataGridView. Just use one of the events to highlight the row when the search item is found.  You'll need a form level variable for the target.  We *did* understand the first version

Answer (score 0):

If you know the **searchKey** say *Name* and the **column number** of Name in DGV, just use a for loop.

> Example:
>
> ```
>     Dim key = "Andrew"
>     Dim col_Name = 5
>     For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvCSV.Rows
>         If r.Cells(col_Name).Value = key Then
>             Return r.Index
>         End If
>     Next
> ```